# Tilde (~) inside working unix directory

Tags: shell, filenames, home

I'm working in a UNIX environment and I noticed that inside my working directory, which is miles and miles away from my UNIX home, there is a `~`.

Now, once in the past, I did `rm -rf ~` from my working directory and ended up erasing my home directory completely and had to involve IT.

I do not want to do it again. At the same time, I want to know:

1. Why is `~` created in my working directory? Is it a faulty finger slip while saving (`:w!` but what happens is `:w~` ?!!)
2. Before checking in, there is a script that looks for extra files or folders that p4 is not aware so this `~` might cause an issue. How can I remove the `~` from my working directory and at the same time not erase my home?

I do have a backup command called `del` that I use instead of `rm -rf`. It just places stuff in a temporary location. I could use that and get rid of the `~`, but I'm more interested in knowing why this happens, and how I can remove it.

Answer (score 40):

Either quote it:

```
rm -i '~'
rm -i "~"
rm -i \~
```

Or reference it by a path, instead of just a basename:

```
rm -i ./~
rm -i /path/to/~
```

Note that, despite being a funny-looking single character name, this is conceptually no different than if you had created a file named `SOME$PATH` by doing

```
touch 'SOME$PATH'
```

And tried to remove it by doing:

```
rm -i SOME$PATH
```

(*Warning: the variable* `SOME$PATH` *is not quoted for the sake of the example here. Normally it would be enclosed in quotes* `'SOME$PATH'` *)*

In both cases, the shell is expanding the name you give, and you need to prevent that.

Also: Don't use `rm -rf` to remove a file!  The entire purpose for `rm -r` is to tell `rm` it's OK to remove directories.  If you don't want to accidentally remove entire directories while trying to remove files, don't habitually pass `-r`!

Comment: I just tested this. `:w~` in vim did create a file called `~`. `rm ~` returned `cannot remove /home/seth it is a directory`. `rm "~"` did remove the *file*. Just to underline *don't pass `-rf` automatically*.

Comment: +1 for recommending to omit violent options by default. This is akin to doing `kill -9` by default, which I've seen.

Comment: I see that the example `rm -i $FOO` intentionally does not quote the variable for the sake of the example, but still: showing a shell example involving `rm` and an unquoted variable as argument is **VERY BAD**, uh, sorry, independent of context. I'm sure that can even be prooven :) I'll add some note - but maybe you could change the example, a little?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel, Point taken - I took part of your edit, but the footnote seemed a bit too heavy handed.  I also switched to a variable name even less likely to cause problems - most people don't have a file named `SOME/bin:/usr/bin` anywhere on their filesystem.  :)

Comment: Yes, looks good! (I was almost going to answer: What? Heavy-handed? Did you ever experience a real quoting problem in your live? ;) Just somewhat desparate about the amount of wrong shell examples out there, in general... Hey, it's hard to understand even without wrong examples! )

Answer (score 1):

The tilde when used alone in the context of `ls ~` will list your home dir as ~ is a shortcut to your home dir.  If you did `ls ~brown` then you will list the contents of brown's home dir.

VIM, unless told otherwise, will create a back-up copy of a changed file:  myFile myFile~.

This behavior is good as it creates a back-up but if you don't want it, add to you .vimrc file:   set no backup  (which I just accessed with `vi ~/.vimrc`).

And of course as others said, if you have a file called ~ then simply escape the char as \~

```
me 217 % vi this      (saved as :w~)
me 218 % ls
this  ~
me 219 % cat \~
kfdkdfk
me 220 % \rm \~
me 221 % ls
this
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be effected by mistypes. If your `TERM=xterm` config is anything like mine, then practically every function key on your keyboard will send escape sequences like...

```
infocmp -1 | grep -n \~ | tail -n3
138:    kich1=\E[2~,
141:    knp=\E[6~,
142:    kpp=\E[5~,
```

More than half of the output of `infocmp -1` contains `~`*tilde* escapes on my machine - and I'm at a loss to understand what most of them do. I do know that `zsh` at least actually eats the escaped portion of the string in most cases - and leaves only the `~`*tilde*.

For example, typing `echo` then *`<space>`* then `F6` and *`<return>`* prints...

```
/home/mikeserv
```

The actual escape sequence sent is...

```
kf6=\E[17~
```

Interestingly, there are other of these escape sequences which contain `>` characters.

```
infocmp -1 | grep \>
is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>,
rmkx=\E[?1l\E>,
rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>,
```

Those are commonly used escapes - reset and initialization strings. It's not difficult to imagine that a dropped keyboard or button-smash of some kind when an interactive shell is awaiting input could result in randomly truncated `~` files occurring throughout your file-system. At least, it does occasionally crop up on mine.